# Apache:Camel Request body gets lost after using log component

Tags: java, apache-camel, esb

Whenever I use `.log()` in my routes the next route receives an empty body.
On adding `.streamCaching()` in the beginning this is resolved, but is this the way I will always have to use. Also will `streamCaching` have any other effect on the other components?
To call the route I am using `ProducerTemplates.asyncSendBody()`

Answer (score 1):

From [Camel's official documentation](https://camel.apache.org/stream-caching.html):

> While stream types (like `StreamSource`, `InputStream` and `Reader`) are commonly used in messaging for performance reasons, they also have an important drawback: **they can only be read once**. In order to be able to work with message content multiple times, the stream needs to be cached.

So, your issue lies with the fact that the call to `.log()` will actually read the stream and if it is not cached then subsequent reads will result in no data being return.